# AVPlayerLayer lock screen control

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using AVPlayerLayer to play video and playing the audio of video when app goes in background. Is there any way I can manage controls when screen is locked. User wants to stop play the audio.

My app is working in background but controls are not visible so user have to open the app and stop the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution simply used MPRemoteCommandCenter and added details about video see code in Objetive C

// to setup the playing info

```
- (void) setupNowPlayingInfoCenter{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    [commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
    [commandCenter.playCommand setEnabled:YES];
    [commandCenter.pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
    [commandCenter.nextTrackCommand setEnabled:NO];
    [commandCenter.previousTrackCommand setEnabled:NO];
    [commandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        [self->_player play];
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];

    [commandCenter.pauseCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        [self->_player pause];
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
}
```

// to update the playing info when enter in background

```
- (void) updateNowPlayingInfoCenter {

    NSDictionary *metadata = [self.media metaData];
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *playingInfoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [songInfo setObject:metadata[MIBMediaMetaDataTrackNameKey] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:metadata[MIBMediaMetaDataTrackNameKey] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [songInfo setObject:metadata[MIBMediaMetaDataTrackDurationKey] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(!self.playing ? 0.0f : 1.0f)] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
    [playingInfoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
}
```

// add this line of code in init or viewdidload

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:)
                       name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                     object:nil];
```

Called these 2 methods when enter in background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

     [self setupNowPlayingInfoCenter];
     [self updateNowPlayingInfoCenter];
}
```